# how to vertically center the content of a table with bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically center a table using just bootstrap, but I can't. I have managed to align it horizontally but vertically I don't know how. This is the code I have:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/bootstrap.css" TYPE="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/utilidades.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container d-flex flex-row  justify-content-center alig-items-center">
    <table border="1">
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: read the accepted answer until the end (I insist on *until the end*)

Comment: none worked for me.